# Do epub 3.0 pagebreaks always require an id?

Tags: epub, page-break

Is it within the EPUB 3.0 specification to have a pagebreak span without an id?

I.e.
`<span epub:type="pagebreak" title="2"></span>`

Comment: I don't see any mention of it here: http://www.idpf.org/epub/vocab/structure/#pagebreak or here: http://www.idpf.org/accessibility/guidelines/content/xhtml/pagenum.php. All examples in the spec do include an ID though. Is there a reason why you don't want to include it?

Answer (score 1):

Pagebreaks are usually used in conjunction with nav document [page-list](http://www.idpf.org/epub/301/spec/epub-contentdocs.html#sec-xhtml-nav-def-hidden) sections and since you need an id to refer to pagebreak markers in the book it'd be rather pointless to use pagebreaks without ids and a corresponding page-list section.

You can find an IDPF-approved sample epub3 book with pagebreaks and a page-list nav section [here](https://github.com/IDPF/epub3-samples/tree/master/30/childrens-literature/EPUB).